# i installed ubuntu for chromeos but it did not come with apt-get.

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, apt-get, google-chrome-os

i installed ubuntu for chromeos but it did not come with apt-get. 
I am using chromeos. 
Uname -a output is armv71. 
I installed ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You can probably get your answer from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/77957/where-can-i-download-the-apt-package-if-apt-get-is-missing

Answer (score 0):

sudo enter-chroot
must access proper file location 
clearly dont understand file architecture must work on 
https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/1533